Why is Ubuntu unable to find Wi-Fi Adapter
Earlier in the day, I was on-line with no problems and have now found that somehow Ubuntu can't find the adapter it was using. I made no changes to the system whatsoever and have turned auto-update off, because I don't trust it having seen too many problem with it in the past. I'm running Ubuntu 24.04

Did you try rebooting? Also, can you try booting a live USB to check if it can detect the adapter? That will reveal whether it is problem specific to your ubuntu installation or a generic hardware issue.

"I made no changes to the system whatsoever and have turned auto-update off" hmmm

So you have disabled the OS s ability to fix itself. Interesting.

I second re-enabling unattended-upgrades. On to the issue, there are many things that can cause it, for example the adapter's moule not being loaded (which can happen because of a kernel upgrade + no DKMS support, or perhaps because of something that went wrong with DKMS), but first thing I'd check would be lsmod to see if the module for the adapter is even loaded.
